# How to get the name of the GUI component in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I need to be able to have a list of components in a class and their respective variable name. I did manage to get the list of all the components in the GUI. However when I call the getName method for the component, a null is being returned. Does anyone know how to be able to get such a name for a component please?

This is the code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Calculator c = new Calculator();

    List<Component> containers = getAllComponents(c.getContentPane());
    for (int i = 0; i < containers.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(containers.get(i).getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(containers.get(i).getName());
    }
    System.exit(0);
}

public static List<Component> getAllComponents(final Container c) {
    Component[] comps = c.getComponents();
    List<Component> compList = new ArrayList<Component>();
    for (Component comp : comps) {
        compList.add(comp);
        if (comp instanceof Container) {
            compList.addAll(getAllComponents((Container) comp));
        }
    }
    return compList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getName()` will only return a value if you called `setName()` before. But that name is arbitrary. It's a debugging aid for UI developers.

My guess is that you want to know which component is in which field of the `Calculator` class. For this, you need to use the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Try `Calculator.class.getDeclaredFields()`. To read the value of a private field, see [this example code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html).

Comment: I did manage to get the names and type of variables... I think I'll be able to continue my implementation in this way... thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

The `getName()` method for components is not guaranteed to return a value, and certainly does not return the variable name the component was assigned too. Also note that it's possible for several variables to point to the same object instance, so that information would be less than useful even if it was available.

Comment: so there isn't a way to be able to get the name of the variable for a compoenent?

Comment: You can't perform static analysis on your code, but thats a pretty radical step to take for I'm sure is a simple requirement. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am building a tool and ultimately I need to be able to identify some components which I need to highlight. So I need the actual components and the name of the variables. At first I also tried to use the getX and getY to be able to locate the component but a zero is being returned.

Comment: You could always obtain the object instances, but the component will only have a name if it was assigned one (by the developer or the framework). And like I said, variable names just won't be available at runtime. Imagine a UI that was created entirely in the context of a method that has gone out of scope. There are no more 'variables' pointing to those components, just references on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Each Component can have a name, accessed via getName() and setName(), but you'll have to write your own lookup function.

You can also try with HashMap. I find an example with that.

```
    Create a Map class variable. You'll need to import HashMap at the very least. I named mine componentMap for simplicity.

private HashMap componentMap;

    Add all of your components to the frame as normal.

initialize() {
    //add your components and be sure
    //to name them.
    ...
    //after adding all the components,
    //call this method we're about to create.
    createComponentMap();
}

    Define the following two methods in your class. You'll need to import Component if you haven't already:

private void createComponentMap() {
        componentMap = new HashMap<String,Component>();
        Component[] components = yourForm.getContentPane().getComponents();
        for (int i=0; i < components.length; i++) {
                componentMap.put(components[i].getName(), components[i]);
        }
}

public Component getComponentByName(String name) {
        if (componentMap.containsKey(name)) {
                return (Component) componentMap.get(name);
        }
        else return null;
}

    Now you've got a HashMap that maps all the currently existing components in your frame/content pane/panel/etc to their respective names.

    To now access these components, it is as simple as a call to getComponentByName(String name). If a component with that name exists, it will return that component. If not, it returns null. It is your responsibility to cast the component to the proper type. I suggest using instanceof to be sure.
```